# Puedo con python hacer un generador de reportes tipo excel

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una duda, necesito hacer un modulo de registro e impresión de resultados de laboratorio, para ello necesito que el usuario pueda entrar en un formulario y definir los titulos, los valores de referencia , la cantidad de filas y por cada fila definir cuantas columnas va a usar (combinar las columnas como lo hace excel) mi pregunta es puedo hacer esto con python y tkinter? o mejor trato de utilizar excel llamándolo desde python? o existe alguna otra alternativa que pueda ayudarme con este módulo.

Comment: Toda la parte de manejo de datos puede hacerla perfectamente python de forma muy sencilla. Sin embargo la interfaz de usuario puede ser muy complicada de poner a punto (aunque también entra dentro de lo posible). Y la parte de "impresión" que mencionas supongo que requiere la generación de algún PDF, lo que también puede ser complicado. Para estas cosas podría ser más sencillo usar Excel.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias. osea lo mejor es utilizar excel desde python y almacenar los valores de la hoja de excel en la base de datos, para mantener el histórico y poder dar la opción de reimprimirlos, es decir guardar cada hoja como un formato y pasarle los datos desde la base de datos cunado los quiera reimprimir o consultar. LIsto muchas gracias por responderme, ya tengo una luz para empezar a desarrollar la solución, de verdad muchas gracias